# Average of dates per months to Graph, how?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, date, average

I working on a website codeigniter based. In my database i have a lot of dates in this format:
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

What i want is to represent in a graph, all the 12 months, and for each month the total of dates that i have on my database. For now just a graph for 2012, next year ill change it for 2013.

How can i do it? Any ideas?

I searched a lot for javascript graph/tables such as in google api but none of them gave me everything i needed. Also, how can i read from database the dates and "put them" in each month.

Thanks

Comment: Is your biggest problem in how to aggregate the data by month (an SQL issue) or to display a graph (which does not necessarily require javascript)?

Comment: `SELECT avg(somefield) ... GROUP BY year(yourdatefield)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first extract your average dates from Database with for example this code:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)),0) as avg_time
FROM `data`
WHERE `id`>0
GROUP BY Month(`date`)
```

This SQL works fine and returns average `unix_timestamp` rounded to the nearest and grouped in Months. In PHP code u can easily cover back to datetime format if needed.
Also u can add in `WHERE` closure check for year. For example: `WHERE YEAR(date)=2012`.

Good luck :)